# command prompt java path error

Tags: java, windows

```
C:\>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02

C:\>set path=./;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin;%path%

C:\>set classpath=%classpath%;

C:\>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  ... (rest stripped)


C:\>javac sa1.java

C:\>java sa1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sa1

C:\>
```

I have installed java in c drive I have set path properly but prg is not running.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your classpath does not contain the execution-directory `C:>set classpath=%classpath%;`

try `C:>set classpath=.;%classpath%;`

Answer (score 0):

```
C:>set path=./;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin;%path%
```

Think the problem is with the ./
Take away the forward slash

```
C:>set path=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin;%path%
```

If your classpath does not have the current directory .
Put that in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your java source file compiles (with the current classpath settings) but won't execute. Do you need additional jars to execute the application? If not, please delete the `CLASSPATH` variable. If there is no classpath set through this variable or the `-cp` parameter, it defaults to the working directory (`.`) which is OK in most cases.

Double check the package definition of your `sa1` class, if it is located in the correct directory and if you're in the correct working directory. Just an example:

```
 package com.example;
 public class Test {}
```

The compiled class file needs to be stored in `./com/example/Test.class`. Then you can execute the application (imagine it has a main method) with `java com.example.Test`